# MS SQL code sanity check

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, left-join

I'm relatively new with MS Sql Server and its syntax and just wanted to make sure I'm understanding this code correctly.  I've been passed some old code and see this:

```
select * into [FedScope Employment].[dbo].[2011_2015_Employment] from (select 
  A.Year,
  D.AGYT as ParentAgency,
  D.AGYSUBT as ChildAgency,
  E.LOCTYPT as Country,
  E.LOCT as State,
  B.AGELVLT AS Age,
  H.edlvlt as Education,
  A.gender as Gender,
  A.gsegrd as GSEGrade,
  F.LOSLVLT as LengthofService,
  G.OCCT as Occupation,
  G.OCCFAMT as OccupationFamily,
  G.OCCTYPT as OccupationCategory,
  A.PPGRD as PayGrade,
  I.SALLVLT as SalaryLevel,
  A.TOA as TypeOfAppointment,
  J.WORKSCHT as WorkSchedule,
  A.Salary as Salary,
  A.LOS as LevelOfService,
  A.DATECODE as EffectiveDate,
  'Null' as SeparationType,
  'Null' as AccessionType,
  A.FedscopeType as FedscopeType

  from [FedScope Employment].[dbo].[2011_2015_Employment_raw] A Left JOIN 
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[DTagelvl] B   ON A.AGELVL= B.AGELVL Left JOIN 
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[FY14_DTagy]  D ON A.AGYSUB = D.AGYSUB Left JOIN
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[DTloc] E ON A.LOC = E.LOC Left JOIN
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[DTloslvl] F ON A.LOSLVL = F.LOSLVL Left JOIN
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[FY14_DTocc] G ON A.OCC = G.OCC Left JOIN
    [FedScope Employment].[dbo].[FY15_DTedlvl] H on A.EDLVL = H.EDLVL Left JOIN
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[DTsallvl] I on A.SALLVL = I.SALLVL Left JOIN
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[DTwrksch] J on A.WORKSCH = J.WORKSCH) as tmp;
```

I'm confused about the two select statements at the very beginning of the code.  Shouldn't the code be something like this instead?

```
select 
  A.Year,
  D.AGYT as ParentAgency,
  D.AGYSUBT as ChildAgency,
  E.LOCTYPT as Country,
  E.LOCT as State,
  B.AGELVLT AS Age,
  H.edlvlt as Education,
  A.gender as Gender,
  A.gsegrd as GSEGrade,
  F.LOSLVLT as LengthofService,
  G.OCCT as Occupation,
  G.OCCFAMT as OccupationFamily,
  G.OCCTYPT as OccupationCategory,
  A.PPGRD as PayGrade,
  I.SALLVLT as SalaryLevel,
  A.TOA as TypeOfAppointment,
  J.WORKSCHT as WorkSchedule,
  A.Salary as Salary,
  A.LOS as LevelOfService,
  A.DATECODE as EffectiveDate,
  'Null' as SeparationType,
  'Null' as AccessionType,
  A.FedscopeType as FedscopeType


into [FedScope Employment].[dbo].[2011_2015_Employment]

  from [FedScope Employment].[dbo].[2011_2015_Employment_raw] A Left JOIN 
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[DTagelvl] B   ON A.AGELVL= B.AGELVL Left JOIN 
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[FY14_DTagy]  D ON A.AGYSUB = D.AGYSUB Left JOIN
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[DTloc] E ON A.LOC = E.LOC Left JOIN
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[DTloslvl] F ON A.LOSLVL = F.LOSLVL Left JOIN
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[FY14_DTocc] G ON A.OCC = G.OCC Left JOIN
    [FedScope Employment].[dbo].[FY15_DTedlvl] H on A.EDLVL = H.EDLVL Left JOIN
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[DTsallvl] I on A.SALLVL = I.SALLVL Left JOIN
    [FedScope Accessions].[dbo].[DTwrksch] J on A.WORKSCH = J.WORKSCH) as tmp;
```

Are these two statements the same thing?  Trying to think why there needs to be a select * into then a from select, or if that's totally unneeded.  Thanks.

Comment: I see no reason for the former. There may be performance reasons or it may just be messy code. I would have done the latter. Did it work?

Comment: You would need to remove the `) as tmp;` from the last line, wouldn't you?

Comment: Listing columns instead of a * is a good practice because you have control  over which columns are used. IMHO using * is lazy.

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks.  they both run and seemingly do the same thing.  just wanted to know if they were indeed the same since I'm pretty new at this.  I'm guessing the former is just messy code.  thanks!

Comment: Actually, although just adding comments instead is probably preferable, it strikes me that the original code has the virtue of not burying in the middle the fact that it is creating a new table. So the aim may simply have been to make to code more 'readable'.